# why is git hanging when I change a zip file inside it

Tags: git, zip

I've many git repositories on my machine, never seen this behaviour - created a small repository for releasing lambdas - basically it has two or three files in it, including a 700 byte zip file - so the whole repository is *tiny*

if I change the zip file and run

```sh
   git add --all
```

OR

```
   git commit -m "some change"
```

then git just hangs forever - I have to kill it.  But if I kill it - then the add or commit has happened.

I'm on windows and calling git from a bash script (running git bash)

If I change a non-zip file git works like it normally should and comes back instantly.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Are you using an antivirus other than Windows Defender?  It's likely it's noticing the zip file and intercepting it to scan it.  If so, uninstall it, restart, and use Windows Defender.

Comment: interesting - good theory and may be correct - unforunately - corporate environment - so uninstalling the virus scanner is somewhat of a no-no... and for similar reasons I don't have access to add exclusions - however it gives me avenues for investigation - so thanks!

Comment: If it's not that, maybe it is a Git hook that your corporate environment shoved on you without telling you, that has a bug in it, that causes the zip inspector to hang, making Git wait forever. You'll need a reproducer to track this down, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Check first with a [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (which does not require installation, and is compatible with a corporate environment) if there are any process keeping an handle on that zip file.

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and then the name of the zip file.

On recent Windows 10 2020+ (which, in a corporate setting, might not be the case), Windows 10 has a built-in ransomware block, which often tripped me, by *not* allowing a legitimate process (like `git`) to access a file/folder. If you have such a recent Windows, check that too.

Comment: yeah - looked at that (not using process explorer, but using sysinternals handle.exe) - and I jsut see two git processes.  It's always two - if I taskkill /im:git.exe /f, validate there's none, then run the git command again - I see two

Comment: @DarrenOakey Use Process Explorer to see what is the parent process (and its associated command-line) for those two `git.exe`. For example, I often see on from VSCode, which does regular fetch from the upstream remote repository.